# How to make a scroll area hide x & y both scroll bar, but only enable horizontal scroll?

Tags: jquery, css

How to make a scroll area hide x & y both scroll bar, but only enable horizontal scroll?

http://jsbin.com/opunut/5/edit

There's a demo in here http://jsbin.com/acexuq/1/edit but it is vertical, if I set wrap overflow-y: hidden; overflow-x: scroll; content float: left, the content can't be scroll..

I find this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2597343/1927742 but it can't hide scroll bar...

Any suggestion or better idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding an extra div between outer & inner called middle & use this CSS:

http://jsbin.com/acexuq/3/

```
#outer {
  overflow:hidden;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
#inner {
  overflow:auto;
  width:4000px; 
  height:400px;
}
#middle {
  overflow: scroll;
  width:417px; 
  height:417px;
}
```